# Erro ao fazer requisição sem refresh no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, requisição

Galera, estou fazendo um sistema que ao pesquisar o nome de um acesso no campo de pesquisa, ele busca no banco de dados alguma palavra referente aquilo que o usuario escreveu no input... eu segui um tutorial do youtube para fazer pois isso que eu queria.

Codigo Javascript no final do index.php

```
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 l12">
                        <input id="pesquisa" name="pesquisa" type="text">
                        <label for="pesquisa">Pesquisar Acesso...</label>
                    </div>
                </form>

<script>
    $("#pesquisa").keyup(function(){
    var busca = $("#pesquisa").val();

    $.post('pesquisaAcesso.php', {busca: busca},function(data){
      $("#result").html(data);
    });
  });

</script>
```

Código do pesquisaAcesso.php

pastebin.com/Fnji0tLX

coloqueio no pastebin pois aqui o código .php fica sem indentaçao

Enfim, quando eu tento pesquisar o nome do acesso no campo, ele me retorna o erro a seguir. Ele nao esta pegando o dado passado via post, se eu modifico a variavel para um acesso que tenha no banco, ele pesquisa normal, mas no $_POST ele nao pega o valor que é colocado no input.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Troque `$_POST['pesquisa']` por `$_POST['busca']`

Comment: deu certo!!!!!!!!!! valeu cara, mas por que a troca do $_POST['pesquisa'] por $_POST['busca'] ?? o $_POST ele puxa da var busca, certo ?

Comment: Exato, você definiu o campo como *busca*: `{busca: busca}` e usou *pesquisa*.

Comment: Aliás, obviamente, você pode fazer o oposto, mudar o nome *busca* para *pesquisa* no seu javascript. A questão não foi mudar o nome de um campo, mas usar o que foi passado pelo JS.

Comment: Entendi! valeu galera. Vou estudar javascript, pois ainda não sei nada. Eu seguir um tutorial no youtube para fazer isso. Valeu!!!